# What are good limits to set for IIS Dynamic IP restriction module?

Tags: iis, ddos

I recently tried to use the default settings, this is:

5 - max number of concurrent occurances
-20 max number of requests in 200 milliseconds.

However, this started cutting of my personal connections to the website (loading javascript, css etc.). I need something that will never fire for users using the site honestly, but I do want to prevent denial of service attacks.

What are good limits to set?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a good generic limit that will fit for all websites, it is personal for each website. It depends on RPS, requests execution time etc.

I suggest you to modify IIS logger and log IP of each request. Then view IIS logs to see what is the pattern of the traffic for users, how many requests they do within a normal flow. It should let you approximate average amount of requests coming from user in a selected time frame.

However in my experience 20 requests without 200 milliseconds usually looks like an attack. In this way default settings provided by IIS seem reasonable.

Comment: any suggestion for tool